# Numbering Tree Array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

a have i tree array, looks like this:

```
$testArray = array(
  array(
    'id' => 12,
    'address' => 'root addr',      
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'children' => array(
      array(
        'id' => 11,
        'address' => 'child addr',                  
        'parent_id' => 12,
        'children' => array(
          array(
            'id' => 16,
            'address' => 'child addr 2',
            'parent_id' => 11,
            'children' => array(
              array(
                'id' => 19,
                'address' => 'child addr 3',
                'parent_id' => 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          array(
            'id' => 18,
            'address' => 'child addr 4',
            'parent_id' => 11,
          ),
          array(
            'id' => 20,
            'address' => 'child addr 5',
            'parent_id' => 11,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 17,
    'address' => 'root addr 2',        
    'parent_id' => 0,
  ),
);
```

i have a function to build array with one level:

```
$result = array('aaData' => array());

function printTree($data, $level = 0, $p_counter = 1) {    

            foreach ($data as $item) {  

                if ($item['parent_id'] == 0) {
                    $addr =  $p_counter . '. ' . $item['address'];
                    $p_counter++;                    
                }

                else if ($item['parent_id'] != 0) {

                    $addr =  strLevel(' - ', $level) . $item['address'];  


                } else {
                     $addr = $item['address'];              
                }

                global $result;

                $result['aaData'][] = Array(
                 $addr,

             );  

                if (isset($item['children'])) {                    
                    printTree($item['children'], $level + 1, $p_counter);
                }


            }

 return $result;        
}
```

another function to try draw numbering, but it's not what i want:

```
function strLevel($str, $level) {
    $level++;
    $result = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i < $level; $i++) {

      if ($i == 1) {
        $result .= $i . ' - ' . $i;
      } else {

      $result .= $str.$i;
    }
  }

  $result .= '.';
  return $result;
}
```

My output is something like this:

```
1. root addr
1 - 1.child addr
1 - 1 - 2.child addr 2
1 - 1 - 2 - 3.child addr 3
1 - 1 - 2.child addr 4
1 - 1 - 2.child addr 5
2. root addr 2
```

But i need to get another numeric structure, like this:

```
1. root adrr
1-1. child adrr
1-1-1. child child addr
1-2. child addr
1-2-1. child child addr
1-3. child addr
1-3-1. child child addr
2. second root adr
2-1. child addr
2-1-1. child child addr
```

i need help, to build this numeric, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish your task without using `parent_id` fields at all and without auxillary `strLevel` function.

Just traverse your nested array in function calling the same function recursively if children nodes exist. The recursively called function should receive additional argument `$prefix` from its caller to render appropriately the higher levels of hierarchy.

In your example, `$prefix` will be `1-` for the second layer of hierarchy, `1-1-` for 3rd and `1-1-1-` for 4th.

```
function printTree($arr, $prefix = "")
{
    $output = "";
    $index = 1;
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $output .= $prefix . $index . "." . $item["address"] . "<br/>";
        if (array_key_exists("children", $item))
            $output .= printTree($item["children"], $prefix . $index . "-");
        $index++;
    }
    return $output;
}

echo printTree($testArray);
```

The output for your test array `$testArray` is

```
1. root addr
1-1. child addr
1-1-1. child addr 2
1-1-1-1. child addr 3
1-1-2. child addr 4
1-1-3. child addr 5
2. root addr 2
```

P.S.: The solution assumes that you generate HTML as output. If you are going to send output to console, do not forget to change `<br/>` to `\n`.

Comment: Not quite sure on the wording, but give a man a fish, feed him for a day.  Teach a man to fish, feed him for a life time.(eg, explain your answer)

Comment: @Deadalus May be this one is better a little bit

Comment: great, thanks! i want to put data in array with the same hierarchy, when i change  output to output[], order is broken

Comment: @user3111525 Works good for me. Did you change both occurrences of `$output`?